# Ruby get array of subvalues from hash

Tags: ruby, hash, hashtable

I have a hash like this:

```
members = { "name1" => { "country" => "country1", "city" => "city1"}, "name2" => { "country" => "country2", "city" => "city2"} }
```

How can I get an array of countries from this hash like:

```
countries = [ "country1", "country2" ]
```

Comment: countries = members.collect { |_,v| v["country"] }

Comment: Don't know why this was put on hold, I've got several working answers so I'm not the only one who knows what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { members.map { |_,v| v["country"] } }
  x.report { members.collect { |_,v| v["country"] } }
  x.report { members.values.map{|h| h["country"]} }
end

  user     system      total        real
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000014)
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000011)
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000020)

=> ["country1", "country2"]
```

So, use `members.collect { |_,v| v["country"] }` as it is the fastest.

Comment: Please, don't post benchmarks with just one method call, it does not make sense, these values are too small, it's just random that the last one was the slowest for you (I ran it for 10000 iterations and the last one was the fastest actually). Also - `map` and `collect` are aliases, it's just different name for the same method.

Comment: Just to reiterate, `map` and `collect` are the same function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 countries = members.to_a.map(&:last).map{|h| h["country"]}
```

I tested and it should work.

Comment: `to_a.map(&:last)` is equivalent to `.values` in this case :) `countries = members.values.map{|h| h["country"]}`.

Comment: Even ignoring `#values` it seems like converting to an array and collecting then throwing away the second value seems redundant.

Comment: I,ve implemented Daniël's simple notation and yes, it works perfectly!